# WIX - Unable to create a SQL database or run SQL scripts

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm new to WIX and I'm having some problems executing SQL scripts. I have looked at a number of posts and none of them have worked. I have also looked for any SQL Server logs that would help and I couldn't find any. The error messages that I'm receiving in the install log are...

CreateDatabase:  Error 0x80004005: failed to create to database: 'MVDB', error: unknown error 
Error 26201. Error -2147467259: failed to create SQL database: MVDB, error detail: unknown error. 
MSI (s) (A4!F4) [13:21:44:978]: Product: Guru 6 -- Error 26201. Error -2147467259: failed to create SQL database: MVDB, error detail: unknown error.

CustomAction CreateDatabase returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

If I go into SQL Server Management Console I can create the database and run all of the scripts using the same user that I am logged on with when I execute the installer.

My code looks like this...

```
<DirectoryRef Id="SERVER">
  <Component Id='Server.exe' Guid='8027388d-0f90-465b-9668-d1388977caaa'>
    <File Id='Server.exe' Source='C:\VS Publish\ProgramFiles\Server\Server.exe' KeyPath='yes'/>
    <ServiceInstall 
      Id="ServiceInstaller" 
      Type="ownProcess" 
      Name="Service" 
      DisplayName="Service" 
      Description="Provides media distribution, data coordination, and licensing services to the  application" 
      Start="auto" 
      Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" 
      Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" 
      ErrorControl="normal" 
      />
    <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="Service" Wait="yes" />
    <util:User Id="SQLUser" Name="[ComputerName]\[%USERNAME]" CreateUser="no"/>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id="SqlDatabase" Database="MVDB" Server=".\MVSQLEXPRESS" Instance="MVSQLEXPRESS" 
        CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" ContinueOnError="no" User="SQLUser">
      <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateDatabase" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateDatabaseSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateUsers" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateUsersSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateBaseLineDb" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateBaseLineDbSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="RemoveOldContent" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="RemoveOldContentSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="Upgrade" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="UpgradeSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="AddCompleteMedia" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="AddCompleteMediaSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="InstallContent" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="InstallContentSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="UpdateCustomPlayList" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="UpdateCustomPlayListSql" />
      <sql:SqlScript Id="InstallFeaturedContent" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="InstallFeaturedContentSql" />
    </sql:SqlDatabase>
  </Component>
```

I have also used...

```
<util:User Id="SQLUser" Name="[%USERNAME]" Domain="[ComputerName]" CreateUser="no"/>
```

I also tried removing the user altogether from the sql:sqldatabase entry. I have checked that all of the network protocols are enabled for the instance and that there is enough disk space for the database.

I just tried to set CreateOnInstall and DropOnUninstall both to no and execute an SQL script to create the database but you cannot set both to "no".

**UPDATE:**  *I changed the util:user to use sa as the user and it worked. So the problem is definitely a permissions issue. 
The problem is that I have to be able to use Windows authentication. When the database is created the flag is set to create the current user as an administrator (ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True"). Also I can see the current user as an administrator. 
How do I have WIX create the database using the current user?*

I would appreciate any help!!

Thanks, 
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by moving the sqldatabase element outside of a component. By doing that the installer is not trying to create the database (I have a script for that) and I no longer need a until:user, the installer seems to be using the current user to run the SQL scripts.

Gary